# expr bash command returning 0 in substring evaluation

Tags: bash, regex

What I'm trying to do is read a line from a file, store it in a variable `$line` and extract all instances of `<UPPERCASE>` (that is, angle brackets with only uppercase letters between them).
What I'm trying is:

```
while read line
do
#some other commands
FOUND=`expr $line : \<[A-Z]*\>`
echo FOUND is:$FOUND
#more commands
```

When I run the script i feed it:

```
<hello><HELLO>
```

output:

```
FOUND is:0
```

I have also tried variations on quotes around the regex bit. i.e.
    `"\<[A-Z]*\>"`
, 
    `'\<[A-Z]*\>'`
and
    `\(<[A-Z]*>\)` Where the last of those returns null.

I've checked out the man page, it should return 0 if zero characters are matched or if the match fails.
I feel like it's something small that I'm overlooking, but after an hour of searching, I still can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `expr` man page: regular expressions are *implicitly anchored*, so if your $line does not *begin* with an upper case word in angle brackets, expr won't find it

```
line="<hello><HELLO>"
expr "$line" : '.*<[[:upper:]]*>'       # => 14
expr "$line" : '.*\(<[[:upper:]]*>\)'   # => <HELLO>
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/String-expressions.html

Note that `expr` is not a bash command, it's a separate program. If you want to do this in bash:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "<"[[:upper:]]*">" ]]; then
    echo "found it"
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
fi
```

Also, [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: Awesome. That works, thanks. What is that `=~` operator though? I can't find it listed with the bash comparison operators. Is it a form of "contains"?

Comment: It's a regular expression matching operator. My guess is they stole it from perl who probably stole it from awk. Documented with the [`[[...]]` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b)

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach to find multiple instances of a pattern in a line? From what I understand, BASH_REMATCH is defined in a subshell, so I'm not able to iterate the process.

Comment: BASH_REMATCH is just a plain (array) variable, declared in the current shell. For multiple matches: `if [[ "$line" =~ pattern1 ]] || [[ "$line" =~ pattern2 ]] || [[ "$line" =~ pattern3 ]] ...` or you could try to cleverly combine all the patterns into a single regular expression but that can quickly become unreadable